# phpmyadmin, 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, mysql, apache, zend-framework, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a small (75k) database SQL file into a new phpMyAdmin install, and am getting:

413 - Request Entity Too Large

php.ini settings:

```
upload_max_filesize = 150M      (originally 2M)
post_max_size = 150M            (originally 8M)
```

phpMyAdmin is not on SSL.
It was installed as part of Zend Community Edition Stack running on Apache

Additionally, I am not seeing the error posted in /usr/local/zend/var/log/access.log

No mods have been installed that I am aware of.

Comment: what about apache's settings? just because php's are high enough doesn't mean you can get through apache's limits.

Comment: only one httpd.conf and it is empty... what else should I look for?